# Multithread security with synchronized in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, synchronized

I'm implementing a program that calculates a Julia set. It will use multiple threads, depending on how many processors are available. Each thread calculates a line, but only when that line is not being calculated by another thread. This part WORKS pretty well.

But sometimes when I test it with bigger images (more lines to calculate, for example instead of `getHeight() = 1200`, I set it to `3000`, there are some lines which are skipped). I want to make it more secure, so that no line will be calculated twice, and no lines will be skipped. Here is the code of the `run()` method:

```
 public void run() {
     while (counter < getHeight()-1) {  
         synchronized(this) {
             if (counter >= getHeight() -1) { //so that the last line will not be calculated >2 times.
                 return;
             }
             counter++;
             image.setRGB(0, counter, getWidth(), 1, renderLine(counter), 0, 0);
         }
     }
  }
```

I want it to work like that: if the current line is being calculated, the thread goes to the next line.. without that it get confused, so that lines get skipped..

I'm trying this actually:

```
 public void run() {
     while (counter < getHeight()-1 && !working) {  
         synchronized(this) {
             working = true;
             if (counter >= getHeight() -1) { //so that the last line will not be calculated >2 times.
                 return;
             }
             counter++;
             image.setRGB(0, counter, getWidth(), 1, renderLine(counter), 0, 0);
             working = false;
         }
     }
  }
```

but I don't know if it will prevent access to another thread, while a thread is already working, and it will change the value of "counter", meaning that lines can be skipped!

Do I need a boolean variable to notify that a thread is actually working on a line? Any advice?

Comment: u can have an array representing `number` of lines that is already readed. But will surely makes app slow if number of line increases.

Answer (score 5):

You're almost certainly doing too much of your own thread management.  Use an `ExecutorService` to distribute the work between multiple threads without duplication.

```
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
   Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
 for (int row = minRow; row <= maxRow; row++) {
   service.submit(new FillThisRowRunnable(row));
 }
```

Comment: I cannot.. It's a homework, and we shouldn't use anything else except for "synchronized" and "simple" methods and modifiers :-) and I have already processors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()); as object variable in my class. I'm just dealing with more safety by calculating the lines of the image. As I said, it's working pretty good now, but if anyone have any advice that it will be safer, it will be very helpful.. Thanks!

Comment: If it's homework, it should be tagged with the [homework] tag.

Answer (score 1):

You would really need to have a shared object for all your threads.  This object will tell the other threads which line to work on.

I can't tell definitely what you have now, but it appears each `synchronized` is on a different instance in which you lose all mutual exclusion.  Remember that synchronizing only works for multiple threads when the synchronization occurs on shared objects, otherwise each thread will sync on thread local objects in which nothing is achieved.

Here is an example

```
public class SharedLineCounter{
   private final int maxNumberOfLines;
   private int currentLineNumber =0;
   public SharedLineCounter(int maxNumberOfLines){
      this.maxNumberOfLines = maxNumberOfLines;
   } 
   public synchronized int getNextLine(){
      if(++currentLineNumber > maxNumberOfLines)
         return -1; //end case
      return currentLineNumber ;
   }
}

public class WorkerThread extends Thread{
    private final SharedLineCounter counter;
    public WorkerThread(SharedLineCounter counter){
       this.counter = counter;
    }
    public void run(){
      int next = -1;
      while((next = counter.getNextLine()) >= 0){
        image.setRGB(0, next , getWidth(), 1, renderLine(next ), 0, 0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here each thread will share this thread safe line counter so each thread should always get a unique and sequential line number.

Edit to answer your question:

You can make the Thread anonymous by sharing a global instance

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    final SharedCounter counter = new SharedCounter();

    Thread worker1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
            counter.getNextLine(); //etc
       }
    });
    Thread worker2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
            counter.getNextLine(); //etc
       }
    });

}
```

One caveat to address based on your comment.  You should pass the `new Runnable` in and create an anonymous runnable, its bad practice to subclass and override the `run` method of the `Thread`

Comment: thanks for your answer! 
Okay, the professor gave us the same class, but using just one processor. So that we can compare our results, if it is fasted or not.. for example if I have 4 processors, with multithreading, it should be done 4 times faster. I though my synchronised was doing something, because if was running 4 times faster than his class (using just 1 processor without threading) when you told me, i commented my sync block, and it still running 4 times faster! O_o
so yes its not doing anything, but how come that it is running 4 times faster that his class?

Comment: Sorry ZelelB I'm having trouble following.  Which class is 4 times faster the one with the shared counter or the one without the shared counter?

Comment: the one i posted.. but without "synchronized" its working 4times faster too, and the image is okay! (no lines skipped)

Comment: Ok, the reason is probably because you have no synchronization points.  If you want all threads to have a unique integer index for a certain line each thread has to wait until the other thread get's their next line.  But to be thread safe you need all threads to wait their turn otherwise you run into a concurrency issue like you were seeing

Comment: Does no synchronization work 100% of the time even when you have 3000 lines, what about 30000 or 3 million?  You run into concurrency issues if multiple threads are incrementing on a shared variable without synchronization

Comment: And the reason to why it is 4 times faster, it's because each thread doesnt care about the other threads and increments the counter (but you have the cost of concurrency issues) so it technically is not correct.

Comment: and if i want to use your solution, how can I make WorkerThread class as an annonymous class? because im using an annonymous class for the threads such as 
`workers[processor] = new Thread() {    public void run() {  blablabla... } };

Comment: @ZelelB On a side note, this does seem like a good lesson in parallelization.  You see a 4 times slow down in speed because you are not parallezing any work (each thread is waiting for the next line).  To speed it up you can give each thread a range of lines to work on so that thread 1 will work on lines 1-500, thread 2 will work on thread 501-1000 and so forth.  You can do that and should see a performance increase.

Comment: i did it, but it got skipping many many lines.. I think I'll use my old version, because it wasnt skipping any lines, just in soooome rare cases, and when it does it, it skipps 1 or 2 line out of 1200.. but thanks nevertheless for all your answers!! :)

Comment: I did it yesterday John, and it was working 100% okay, but the professor ment that we shouldn t do that, and if we do it we get 0 points! he wants that each one takes a line, and when a thread is already calculating a line, the next one should take the one after that, and they should work simultaneously, without skipping or calculating a line 2 times! so i modified the code as posted above, and its got working pretty good on 98% of the cases.. i just wanted to make the multi-threading more safe, because i dont know how he would test it tomorrow.. thanks a lot anyway!!

Comment: @ZelelB With the example above it should be safe, as well as allow multiple threads to work on 1 line at a time while the other threads don't have to wait to get the next line.  Good Luck!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that all threads are using the *the same instance SharedCounter*?

Comment: Hi John, here is my code.. should it be working good? Thanks!
`final Thread[] workers = new Thread[processors];
   for (int processor = 0; processor < processors; processor++) {

   /** Annonyme Klasse, wo die run()-Methode redefiniert wird. */
   workers[processor] = new Thread(new Runnable(){
          public void run(){
           int next=-1;
           counter.getNextLine(); 
              while((next = counter.getNextLine()) >= 0){
                   image.setRGB(0, next, getWidth(), 1, renderLine(next), 0, 0);
              }
          }
       });


   workers[processor].start();
}`